# HTML5 video player with support for video in video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video.js, video-player

A while ago I stumbled across an example of an HTML5 video player with support video in video. In an example use case, the following was demonstrated: a powerpoint presentation video, with an explainer video to accompany it. Unfortunately I can't remember which video player it was.

[To illustrate; something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaiui.jpg)

The beauty of the player is that it's able to serve multiple sources of video in one view and toggle between different view points (like split screen and switched view).

Like I have illustrated here:

[Split screen video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APIWY.jpg)

[Switched video view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arbua.jpg)

Could anyone help me find out which HTML5 video player it may have been, or maybe how this could be achieved in something like VideoJS?

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your requirements that these are completely separate videos.

If this is the case then one simple approach is to just have two video players.

You can then use your web page layout to place them wherever you need them to start up, and add some simple Javascript scripts, linked to buttons on the page for example, to change the layout to however you want it for that particular button (e.g. one button might be for split screen).